# Codename One - qrcode (zxing) scan successful but not returning to main form

Tags: codenameone

I have developing a simple android application then scan qr code and return a text to my form ,
but there is nothing returned from zxing scanner .

note : The zxing's Barcode Scanner App  work perfectly

Comment: It's unclear how you are using zxing? There are two cn1libs with QR/barcode support for Codename One, are you using one of them or are you doing something different?

Comment: @Shai Almog , Thanx , I have using this lib https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/blob/master/cn1-codescan.cn1lib and i have flow this dimo https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/blob/master/src/com/codename1/demos/codescan/CodescanDemo.java

Comment: I suggest removing your installation and installing via the extension manager tool http://www.codenameone.com/blog/automatically-install-update-distribute-cn1libs-extensions.html Do you see the native QR scan app launch?

Comment: Thanks , it works .

Answer (score 1):

Our scanner is a bit sensitive to the app intent fired and might not work with some bad QR scanners. There is a 3rd party scanner that might work more consistently on Android that's available within the extension manager and is based on zbar.